# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function angular-meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, owl-carousel, angular-meteor

I'm using angular-meteor to use this package installing it from here https://atmospherejs.com/richsilv/owl-carousel

on my view I put this

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000" alt="The Last of us"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage2.jpg" alt="GTA V"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage3.jpg" alt="Mirror Edge"></div>

</div>

<script>
$(function(){

$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

    navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    singleItem:true

    // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
    // items : 1, 
    // itemsDesktop : false,
    // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
    // itemsTablet: false,
    // itemsMobile : false

  });
});
</script>
```

But I always get `owlCarousel is not a function` what am I doing wrong?

**edit**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the scripts you're including?

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but, doesn't meteor add the scripts automatically?

Comment: Check if the owl-carousel script is included. Also, if you use angular, use the angular way: https://github.com/jonahbron/angular-owl-carousel

Comment: I added some pictures to the question, it is indeed included, but even in the console it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: You should place your `$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({})` inside a Template.name.onRendered() function. Why do you use a *<script>* tag?

Comment: I'm still new to meteor, but I'm using angular-meteor as well, I'm not sure if this is the right way to implement it, as lack of documentation. I was able to fix my issue by just re-downloading the repository, as I really don't know what was going on, and now I am able to use the owlCarousel with the above code.